# SQlite error when restarting android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I'm using SQlite database to store my `listview` data.
I added opportunities to change listview items, delete them by swiping etc. Everything works fine when I run my app using IDE - data can be deleted or changed, but when I'm trying to restart it using my phone, I get this error:

```
02-04 22:13:03.276 31682-31682/com.example.jeavie.deadlineyesterday E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
02-04 22:13:03.276 31682-31682/com.example.jeavie.deadlineyesterday E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-04 22:13:03.278 31682-31682/com.example.jeavie.deadlineyesterday E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0                                                                                            
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)                                                                                          
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)                                                                                            
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)                                                                                            
at com.example.jeavie.deadlineyesterday.MainActivity$2.onTouch(MainActivity.java:411)                                                                                           
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11772)                                                                                           
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2962)                                                                                           
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2643)                                                                                            
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)                                                                                         
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)                                                                                         
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)                                                                                          
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)                                                                                          
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)                                                                                            
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)                                                                                           
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)                                                                                          
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)                                                                                           
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)                                                                                           
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)                                                                                         
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)                                                                                           
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)                                                                                           
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)                                                                                          
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)                                                                                          
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)                                                                                         
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)                                                                                          
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)                                                                                           
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)                                                                                          
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)                                                                                           
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                           
at com.
```

My **MainActivity** class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public final static int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public final static int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_TWO = 2;
    public static int INTENT_RESULT_CODE = 1;
    public static int INTENT_RESULT_CODE_TWO = 2;
    public final static int INTENT_EMPTY_CODE = 0;
    public static Integer listNumber = 0;
    public static Integer dataNumber = 1;
    public static Integer editNumber = 1;

    //Swiping
    private boolean mSwiping = false; // detects if user is swiping on ACTION_UP
    private boolean mItemPressed = false; // Detects if user is currently holding down a view

    private ListView listView;
    DeadlineActivityAdapter deadlineActivityAdapter;
    List<DeadlineActivity> list;
    String summary, getData, getTime;

    DbActivity db;
    Cursor fullData;
    boolean full;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

        db = new DbActivity(this);

        fullData = db.getAllData();
        if (fullData.getCount() > 0){
            if (fullData.moveToFirst()) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
            do {
                String check = fullData.getString(7);
                if (check.startsWith("li")){
                    summary=fullData.getString(2);
                    getData=fullData.getString(3);
                    getTime=fullData.getString(4);
                    String deadline=fullData.getString(5);
                    String tags=fullData.getString(6);
                    list.add(new DeadlineActivity(String.valueOf(dataNumber - 1), summary, getData, getTime, deadline,
                         tags));
                    full = true;
                    listNumber++;
                }
            } while (fullData.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        if (!full) list = new ArrayList<>();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton addTask = findViewById(R.id.addTask);
        addTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, AddTaskActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listDeadlines);

        TextView emptyText = findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        listView.setEmptyView(emptyText);

        deadlineActivityAdapter = new DeadlineActivityAdapter(this, list, mTouchListener);
        listView.setAdapter(deadlineActivityAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == INTENT_RESULT_CODE){
            if(resultCode == INTENT_RESULT_CODE) {
                Cursor newDeadline = db.getAllData();
                newDeadline.moveToLast();
                summary=newDeadline.getString(2);
                getData=newDeadline.getString(3);
                getTime=newDeadline.getString(4);
                String deadline=newDeadline.getString(5);
                String tags=newDeadline.getString(6);
                list.add(new DeadlineActivity(String.valueOf(dataNumber), summary, getData, getTime, deadline,
                         tags));
                dataNumber++;
                deadlineActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == INTENT_RESULT_CODE_TWO){
            if (resultCode == INTENT_RESULT_CODE_TWO) {
                String a = list.get(editNumber).getId();
                Cursor newDeadline = db.getData(a);
                String id = newDeadline.getString(0);
                summary=newDeadline.getString(1);
                getData=newDeadline.getString(2);
                getTime=newDeadline.getString(3);
                String deadline=newDeadline.getString(4);
                String tags=newDeadline.getString(5);
                list.remove(Integer.valueOf(id) - 1);
                list.add(Integer.valueOf(id) - 1, new DeadlineActivity(id, summary, getData, getTime, deadline, tags));

                deadlineActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.toWeek:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, WeekActivity.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.history:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, HistoryActivity.class));
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {   
            case R.id.tags:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, TagsActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.notifications:
//                startActivity(new Intent(this, HistoryActivity.class));
                return true;    
            case R.id.info:
//                startActivity(new Intent(this, HistoryActivity.class));
                return true;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    float mDownX;
    private int mSwipeSlop = -1;
    boolean swiped;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mSwipeSlop < 0) {
            mSwipeSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(MainActivity.this).getScaledTouchSlop();
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mItemPressed) return false; // Doesn't allow swiping two items at same time
                mItemPressed = true;
                mDownX = event.getX();
                swiped = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                v.setTranslationX(0);
                mItemPressed = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                float x = event.getX() + v.getTranslationX();
                float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);

                if (!mSwiping) {
                    if (deltaXAbs > mSwipeSlop) {
                        mSwiping = true; // tells if user is actually swiping or just touching in sloppy manner
                        listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }
                }
                if (mSwiping && !swiped) { // Need to make sure the user is both swiping and has not already completed a swipe action (hence mSwiping and swiped)
                    v.setTranslationX((x - mDownX)); // moves the view as long as the user is swiping and has not already swiped

                    if (deltaX > v.getWidth() / 3) { // swipe to right
                        mDownX = x;
                        swiped = true;
                        mSwiping = false;
                        mItemPressed = false;

                        v.animate().setDuration(300).translationX(v.getWidth()/3);

                        int i = listView.getPositionForView(v);
                        String a = list.get(i).getId();
                        Cursor newDeadline = db.getData(a);
                        String id = newDeadline.getString(0);
                        summary=newDeadline.getString(1);
                        getData=newDeadline.getString(2);
                        getTime=newDeadline.getString(3);
                        String deadline=newDeadline.getString(4);
                        String tags=newDeadline.getString(5);
                        boolean isInserted = db.updateData(id, id, summary, getData, getTime, deadline, tags, "history");
                        if (isInserted)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deadline completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        list.remove(i);
                        deadlineActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        return true;
                    }
                    else if (deltaX < -1 * (v.getWidth() / 3)) { // swipe to left

                        mDownX = x;
                        swiped = true;
                        mSwiping = false;
                        mItemPressed = false;

                        v.animate().setDuration(300).translationX(-v.getWidth()/3);

                        int i = listView.getPositionForView(v);
                        String a = list.get(i).getId();
                        Cursor newDeadline = db.getData(a);
                        String id = newDeadline.getString(0);
                        summary=newDeadline.getString(1);
                        getData=newDeadline.getString(2);
                        getTime=newDeadline.getString(3);
                        String deadline=newDeadline.getString(4);
                        String tags=newDeadline.getString(5);
                        boolean isInserted = db.updateData(id, id, summary, getData, getTime, deadline, tags, "history");
                        if (isInserted)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deadline completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        list.remove(i);
                        deadlineActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        return true;
                    }
                }

            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                if (mSwiping) { // if the user was swiping, don't go to the and just animate the view back into position
                    v.animate().setDuration(300).translationX(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mSwiping = false;
                            mItemPressed = false;
                            listView.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else { // user was not swiping; registers as a click

                    //set item click "animation"
                    ColorDrawable[] color = {
                            new ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.grey)),
                            new ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.dark_dark_grey))
                    };
                    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
                    v.setBackground(trans);
                    trans.startTransition(1000); // duration 2 seconds

                    // Go back to the default background color of Item
                    ColorDrawable[] color2 = {
                            new ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.dark_dark_grey)),
                            new ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.the_darkest_grey))
                    };
                    TransitionDrawable trans2 = new TransitionDrawable(color2);
                    v.setBackground(trans2);
                    trans2.startTransition(1000); // duration 2 seconds

                    editNumber = listView.getPositionForView(v);
                    String a = list.get(editNumber).getId();
                    Cursor newDeadline = db.getData(a);
                    String id = newDeadline.getString(0);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("number", id);
                    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, EditTaskActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_TWO);

                    mItemPressed = false;
                    listView.setEnabled(true);

                    return true;
                }
            }
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

}
```

I added OnTouch method.

Comment: `at com.example.jeavie.deadlineyesterday.MainActivity$2.onTouch(MainActivity.java:411` indicates where in your code the error stems from. It is imperative that this code be included. Note some bloat has been removed. Please edit your question to include the `onTouch` and especially where it interacts with the database. i.e. it is very likely that you call the DBHelper's `getData` method which looks like it would be problematic.

Comment: @MikeT I included OnTouch method

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was in dataNumber = 1, it was const when restarting that's why when I get full listview in the second time item's position was equal to 0.

Comment: How close was my guess? i.e. in your code you have `Cursor newDeadline = db.getData(a);
                        String id = newDeadline.getString(0);`. Accordingly I suggest that you take heed of the answer I gave re Cursor never being null and checking cursor moves to see if they did in fact move e.g. `if(cursor.moveToFirst)`.

Comment: @MikeT Yeah, you're right, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

At a guess you may be a little confused with how to handle cursors.

The rule so very often found as broken is that a Cursor, unless specifically set to null, will NEVER be null. Any check for a null Cursor is more than likely unnecessary.

Additionally `moveToFirst` without then doing something with that first row may well result in handling issues.

As such I'd suggest that you change the `getData` method to be something like :-

```
public Cursor getData(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return dq.query(true,
        new String[] { DB_NUMBER, DB_SUMMARY,
                    DB_DATE, DB_TIME, DB_DEADLINE, DB_TAGS},
        DB_ID + "=?",
        new String[]{id},
        null,null,null,null
    );
}
```

i.e. just return the cursor as the null check is useless, moveToFirst is quite likely to result in issues.

In the code that calls the **`getData`** method, as it's finding by id and thus only find 1 row then :-

```
    Cursor csr = mydbhlpr.getData();
    if(csr.moveToFirst) {
         //your code to retrieve and act upon the data from the cursor
    } else {
        //your code, if needed, to handle no row being found.
    }
```

My guess is that you've assumed done something like :-

```
    Cursor csr = mydbhlpr.getData(); // assuming it is not empty and moved to first row
    String mydata = csr.getString(whatever_column_offset);
```

#### Note, this is just guessing at what your issue may be (*see comment re adding onTouch*)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use it

Comment: I've done it, you're right. I do not even know how to express my gratitude

Answer (score 0):

- your data base is empty and you are requesting for a row from it
- that's what the error says
- populate your database before querying it for rows
- else include a if statement by checking the cursor size
- call the `DatabaseHelper` `insertData` function from your `MainActivity` to populate the database
- From your `MainActivity` you are just querying data from database
- I do not see anywhere that you have inserted data to you database

Comment: How can it be empty? I'm just restarting app.

Comment: did you insert data into database when the application started for the first time ??

Comment: Yes, as mentioned it works right. There is no problem when I firstly launch app using Android Studio, no any errors. I insert data in another activity launched by FloattingActionButton. I'm sure there is no problem. Data shows again in the list when I restarted the app, but I when I'm trying to edit it - I got this error

Comment: So the error comes from the following package : `com.example.jeavie.deadlineyesterday` ... I really can't say what you are doing wrong unless I see that function but that's what the error message says... If you can give me more details than may be I can help you better

Comment: Seems like your `full` boolean variable is making the list empty when you restart because full is not true at that time ... just guessing

Comment: Here you can find any functions you need, I really despaired to find any solution
  https://github.com/Scarfaiz/DeadlineYesterday

Comment: I'll try to check it now, but list isn't empty when I restarting, so it's a little but strange

Comment: I am not sure on `full` thing... but one thing is sure your database is empty when you are querying for data

Comment: Maybe. The issue is still open

Comment: @Jai the database isn't empty. It most certainly contains a table called Tasks, it will also contain other elements e.g. a table called sqlite_master. Perhaps you mean that you are sure that the Tasks table is definitely empty. However that might not be the case as the query has a where clause which will retrieve at most 1 row from the existing rows. That is the **id** column must be UNIQUE and therefore id=something can only return 1 or 0 rows.